# Process magnetic stripe data through PayPal API

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to process an authorization/payment through PayPal's API using the card magnetic stripe data rather than populating number and other fields?  I'm aware that I can parse the track data and supply the fields they are requesting, but that is still processed as a card-not-present/eCommerce payment with a higher fee than if the payment was processed with the track data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal does have a POS API that allows you to send track data over to PayPal so it's treated as card-present, however, you don't get the lower fee.  PayPal does.  You still pay the 1.9 - 2.9 that you qualify for based on your volume.

Also, that API is only open to a few PayPal Partners.  If you're an official PayPal Partner let me know and I can get you some more details.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  Is there a sandbox where I can test that API by chance while applying for the partnership?  I'll investigate - thanks for the tip.